# Is there a way to add newly added field in one of the indexes to be included in index pattern?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I've an alias setup for rolling indices in elastic search. Let's call the alias : "alias" for now. It points to a number of indexes and rolls over after every 100gb. Now, let's say the number of fields in previous indices associated with alias is 100 and I've added one more field while writing to latest index. so, the number of fields become 101.

I've setup an index pattern by the name of "alias" and I can see all the indices listed via that index pattern but I am unable to visualize the 101th field I just added in the recent indices. Is there a way to do it ?

Please let me know if more details are needed regarding the same.

Comment: Which version of Kibana are you using? Before 7.11, you had to [refresh your index pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.10/index-patterns.html#_refresh_the_data_fields) to pick up new fields. But as of 7.11, the index pattern refresh happens automatically whenever an underlying mapping changes.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you added the new field in the write index that your alias is pointing to, an alias can have only one write index but can have many read index and if you added the new field to a read index of your alias, you will not be able to visualise it using your alias.